# Can I have duplicate foreign keys in Access Database?

Tags: database, ms-access

I am building an Access Database for a class project and had a question about foreign keys. Can I have two duplicate foreign keys in a table?

The reason I'm asking is because I have a Adviser table which uses the adviser's email address as the primary key. However, students can have TWO adviser's so on my student table, can I have two adviser's emails because they would both me the same foreign key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't have a duplicate Primary Key in a table.  It wouldn't be a PK then.
Use a third table to join your students to your advisors.
As an example:
**Advisor Table** has: AdvisorEmail(PK) with values myemail@outlook.com, youremail@ouitlook.com
**Student Table** has: StudentID(PK) with values 1, 2

**StudentAdvisor table** only has two fields: AdvisorEmail and StudentID - both fields set as a Primary Key (a composite Primary Key).
Record 1 has myemail@outlook.com / 1
Record 2 has youremail@outlook.com / 1

You can then write a query to pull back the student name and both advisor names:

```
SELECT      Student.StudentName, 
            Advisor.AdvisorName
FROM        (Advisor INNER JOIN StudentAdvisor ON Advisor.AdvisorEmail = StudentAdvisor.AdvisorEmail) 
                     INNER JOIN Student ON StudentAdvisor.StudentID = Student.StudentID
```